# What is "document" in AWS policy json

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-iam-policy

I was going through one of the beginners course for lambda, when I came across this Execution Role json policy

```
{
"roleName": "lambda_role",
"policies": [
  {
    "document": {
       "version": "2012-10-17",
       "statement": [
       .
       .
       .(contd)
```

Can anyone help me understand what the 'document' refers to here?

Comment: Can you point us to where you saw this? I'm wondering whether it is referring to `AssumeRolePolicyDocument`?

Comment: In this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CgY2uxQPflY&ab_channel=SrceCde around 3:14 timeline.

Comment: The AWS Lambda management console has changed since this video was created. It appears to be looking at the **Execution Role**, which is an IAM Role assigned to the Lambda function. You would normally create this IAM Role in the IAM console and simply reference it from the Lambda function configuration. I have never seen a definition like that displayed in the video, but it seems to be encapsulating the policy document within an IAM Role definition.